# Getting android.os.TransactionTooLargeException When uploading to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an object to firebase. The object includes a photo, title, detail, and timestamp. I'm getting the errors:

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
```

and

```
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1071868 bytes
```

I get the error when trying to upload the photo despite it being small, just 108KB.

Here is the method where I upload the photo and related info to firebase:

```
    private void publishNews() {

    final String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
    final String detail = etDetail.getText().toString();

    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("news");
    StorageReference imgRef = storageReference.child(imgUri.getLastPathSegment());

    final UploadTask uploadTask = imgRef.putFile(imgUri);

    // Show alert for loading
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.CustomTheme_Dialog_Upload)
            .setTitle("Uploading...")
            .setMessage("1 %")

            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        /* Dismiss the dialog */
                    uploadTask.cancel();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_cloud_upload_black_24dp);

    final android.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Upload file to firebase on storageRef location
    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            alertDialog.setMessage((int) progress + " %");
        }
    })
            .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    if(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() == null) {
                        alertDialog.setMessage("Sorry there was a problem");
                        return;
                    }
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Saving...");

                    Uri photoDownloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

                    final HashMap<String, Object> newsObj = new HashMap<>();
                    newsObj.put("photoUrl", photoDownloadUrl);
                    newsObj.put("title", title);
                    newsObj.put("detail", detail);
                    newsObj.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                    database.getReference().child("news").push().setValue(newsObj).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            alertDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                }
            })

            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Failed to upload");
                }
            })

            .addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Upload paused ");
                }
            });

}
```

The code where I get the image uri after picking a photo:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // After picking a photo
    if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        imgUri = data.getData();

        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(imgUri).into(imbAddPhoto); 
    }
}
```

The weird thing is that I was able to do it successfully once, but then I kept getting this error. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: "I get the error when trying to upload the photo despite it being small, just 108KB" -- that may be the size of the photo on *disk*. What matters is the size of the `Bitmap` *in memory*. Photos are compressed on disk. Beyond that, please edit your question and post the entire Java stack trace for your `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think I figured out the  problem. It was the photoDownloadUrl, it has to be a String not Uri.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that photoDownloadUrl has to be a string and not a Uri. Here is the correct version:

```
                    String photoDownloadUrl = String.valueOf(taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());

                    final HashMap<String, Object> newsObj = new HashMap<>();
                    newsObj.put("photoUrl", photoDownloadUrl);
                    newsObj.put("title", title);
                    newsObj.put("detail", detail);
                    newsObj.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```